# Make sure the cron job won't do the same job twice

Tags: mysql, cron, execution, overlapping

I've got a list of similar tasks in mysql database and a PHP-script that takes out 1 task at a time and executes it. When it's done it changes the flag from **pending** to **done**

I want to speed up my performance by adding more scripts(up to 20) running on the same database. How do i make sure these scripts won't be executing the same task twice, ie. processing the same row in the table

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is:

- You can change the datatype of `flag` column to [`ENUM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html) type (if it is not already). It will have three possible Enum values: `pending`, `in_process`, `done`.
- When selecting a `pending` task to do, do an explicit [`LOCK`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html) on the table; so that no other session can update it.

Code example:

```
LOCK TABLES tasks_table WRITE; -- locking the table for read/write

-- Selecting a pending task to do
SELECT * FROM tasks_table
WHERE flag = 'pending' 
LIMIT 1;

-- In application code (PHP) - get the Primary key value of the selected task.

-- Now update the flag to in_process for the selected task
UPDATE tasks_table 
SET flag = 'in_process' 
WHERE primary_key_field = $selected_value;
```

- At the end, **do not forget** to release the explicit lock.

Code:

```
-- Release the explicit Lock
UNLOCK TABLES;
```